# Django1.3 , Python2.7 django-admin.py is not working on windows

Tags: windows, django

I installed Django1.3 on Windows 7 , i made sure i have Python2.7 , Python2.7/Lib and Python2.7/lib/site-scripts/django/bin in my system PATH ...

but, when i try to make django-admin.py creates a new project :

```
django-admin.py startproject exampleproject
```

it opens djangp-admin.py file in text-editor ..

same issue is happening when trying to run GAEFramework - GAE dev_appserver.py

gaeframework/google_appengine/dev_appserver.py

How i can solve this issue ... !

Regards

Comment: nothing works on windows, 'nuff said

Comment: am Linux User too , though needs to make python on windows too :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have probably set up python files to be opened by text editor by default. I just tried installing django on windows and everything works fine

Comment: LOL , THAT WAS RIGHT , i did assigned it to work with PYTHON Int. it's Working ... regarding this is my first Month on Windows since 2002 ... am suck at Windows ... THANK YOU ... :D

Answer (score 1):

you just need to associate `.py` files with python. or run it explicitly:`python django-admin.py startproject exampleproject`